# Why does `ng build` fail but `ng build --verbose` succeed?

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli, angular-http-interceptors

I have an angular library module that exports a basic HttpInterceptor class. I then import this into an application. If I run `ng build` then my build fails while `ng build --verbose` succeeds.

When running `ng build` my build fails with the following:

`Error: export 'HttpErrorInterceptor' (imported as 'HttpErrorInterceptor') was not found`

If I then run `ng build --verbose` my build succeeds with no errors or reference to that class. I would have assumed that these commands are equivalent with additional logging.

It isn't clear to me, through the logs or docs, what `--verbose` might be doing different and how I can prevent this occurring without always passing the `verbose` flag.

The [docs](https://angular.io/cli/build) state: "Adds more details to output logging."

Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the error may have been related the angular cache. I deleted this and ran the build again it everything compiled correctly.

I assume this means that the `--verbose` flag does something differently with the cache.